# Nutch not crawling entire website

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am using nutch **2.3.1**

I preform the commands to crawl a site:

- ./nutch inject ../urls/seed.txt
- ./nutch generate -topN 2500
- ./nutch fetch -all

The problem is, nutch is only crawling the first URL (the one specified in seeds.txt). The data is only the HTML from the first URL/page.

All the other URLS that were accumulated by the generate command are not actually crawled.

I cannot get nutch to crawl the other generated urls...I also cannot get nutch to crawl the entire website. **What are the options that I need to use to crawl an entire site?**

Does anyone have any insights or recommendations?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

In the case that Nutch crawls only one specified URL, please check Nutch filter (conf/regex-urlfilter.txt). To crawl all URLs in the seed, the content of regex-urlfilter.txt should be as follows.

```
# accept all URLs
+.
```

See details here: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do